# useContext prevents static exports in NextJS when using the pages folder

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am having an issue with a Next.JS project where it runs fine with 'npm run dev', and only has this issue when exporting.

In this mini example I stripped almost everything out of componentA except the useContext statement and its still giving me the error so it has to be coming from there but since I have cut back so much and I still can't see what the issue is, so now I am guessing this is either some sort of special situation or I am missing something obvious.

The project exports perfectly fine in most situations but not in the one I need for my project. Specifially it throws errors if I have useContext in a component that gets imported into something in the "Pages" folder.

The errors get thrown in the

"- info Collecting page data
[    ] - info Generating static pages (0/5)"

part of exporting.

The scenarios I tested are below.

Exports with componentA in page.js and not in initial js

Exports without componentA in initial.js

Does not export with component A in initial.js

Exports with "const {state , dispatch} =  useContext(MyContext)" commented out from ComponentA, with componentA in initial.js

Here are the potentially relevant files

componentA.js

```
"use client"
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useContext, useState } from 'react'

import { MyContext } from './mycontext'
export default function ComponentA() {
    const {state , dispatch} =  useContext(MyContext)

return(
    <Fragment>A</Fragment>
)
}
```

initial.js

```
"use client"
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react'
import ComponentA from "../src/app/componentA"
export default function Initial() {

  return (
  <div >
    <ComponentA></ComponentA>
  </div>
  )
}
```

mycontext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import { MyReducer } from "./myreducer";


export const MyContext = createContext();

const MyContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(MyReducer, [], () => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const localData = localStorage.getItem("state");

      return localData && true ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
        }
        return [];

  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  localStorage.setItem("state",JSON.stringify(state))
    }
  }, [state]);
  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyContextProvider;
```

myreducer.js

```
export const MyReducer = (state, action) => {
  
  
   switch (action.type) {
     case "ADD":
       return [...state,{...action}];
      default: 
       return state;
   }
 };
```

page.js

```
"use client"

import ComponentA from './componentA'
import MyContextProvider from './mycontext'
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import Initial from '../../pages/initial'
export default function Home() {
  return (
   <Fragment>
    <MyContextProvider>
      <Initial></Initial>
    </MyContextProvider>

   </Fragment>
  )
}
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
      },
      output: 'export'
  }

module.exports = nextConfig
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "minimumviable",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

Is there some sort of special condition needed for useContext to work in a NextJS "Page"? This is my first project with NextJS and while for this mini example a page isn't really required I am fairly certain it is for the larger project as I will be needing NextJS dynamic routes (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)

The error I am getting (Only when componentA is in initial.js, there is no error when I put it in page.js)

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/initial". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'state' of '(0 , external_react_.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
    at ComponentA
```

The error I am getting in my larger project is slightly different, but hopefully if I understand what is the issue with the small example I can figure out what is going on with the larger project.

Generating static pages (5/6)TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

in the larger project I was able to trace it to a line of code generated by next, in the exported location of .next/server/pages/initial.js
(I did change the names of things here to relate them to the smaller example)

```
function ComponentA() {
  var _useContext = (0,external_react_.useContext)(MyContext),
      state = _useContext.state, //<- This line is the one it is complaining about
      dispatch = _useContext.dispatch;
...
}
```

Since this issue only happens when the component is imported into a file in the Pages folder the structure of the project may be important so here is a screenshot of that.

[image: File Structure]

The list in the previous section of when it does and does not export is what I tried in order to troubleshoot the issue. I was hoping to find some common denominator for what exports and what doesn't but it always exported except in the particular situation that I have my code in.

I am presenting a smallish recreation of a larger project with a similar issue, in the larger project I have also tried some things like.

const {state : aState , dispatch} =  useContext(MyContext)//Nothing changed in the export
const {state , dispatch} =  React.useContext(MyContext)//Nothing changed in the export

I tried putting the useContext call into a conditional statement that checks if things are defined similarly to what I did in the context for localstorage but React does not allow hooks to appear in conditional statements

I tried changing the name of "state" everywhere in the context and when I called useContext in case it was somehow a word that was reserved during export but not while running the dev version, it only changed the word used in the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was not with the static export so much as the hierarchy of elements.

The solution was to restructure the program so that the context provider was available to components without relying on the one in page.js since page.js is not the default starting point on the static export.

It worked in the dev server because there the starting point is page.js which has the context provider to pass to its children. ex: layout.js -> page.js (with context provider) -> initial.js (inherits context provider) -> componentA

This is different from the hierarchy on static exports where page.js is omitted because initial.js is its own page so it ends up as: layout.js -> initial.js -> componentA

The context provider has to be given to initial.js for it to work on the static export. The problem with that is when running on dev you end up with both page.js and initial.js having the context provider which causes issues. So to get around this I removed page.js, and renamed initial.js to index.js which changed the "start point" to index.js for both the dev server and the exported version. This way when giving initial.js/index.js the context provider there are no nested context provider issues.